# 8086 assembly language multiplication

Tags: assembly, cpu, x86-16, cpu-registers, dosbox

here is the basic 8086 program that I use to accept the 2-digit input for qty and 3-digit input price from the user and do multiplication to calculate the total amount.but the problem are some of the calculations are not correct and it can only be displayed in the form of ASCII. If anyone knows how to solve please let me know, Im a beginner this quite hard for me...thanks for your attention.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100
.DATA

askA db 0DH,0AH,"package (unit) (2digit): $"
askB db 0DH,0AH,"package price RM (3digit): $"
Qty db ?
Uprice dw ?
hundr db 100
tens db 10

num_list label byte
max db 4
act db ?
number db 3 dup("$")

reply db 0DH,0AH,"Total amount is RM "
Total1 dw ?
Total2 dw ?,"$"


W_MSG DB 0AH,0DH,"Invalid input! Enter digit only! $"

.CODE
MAIN PROC

MOV AX,@DATA
MOV DS,AX

    JMP sAskA

compare1 PROC

    CMP AL,30h
    JL re_askB
    cmp al,39h
    JG re_askB

    ret
compare1 endp

re_askA:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,W_MSG
    INT 21h

sAskA:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,askA
    INT 21h

    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,num_list
    INT 21h
    mov qty,0

    mov al,number[0]
    call compare1
    sub al,30h
    mul tens
    add qty,al

    mov al,number[1]
    call compare1
    sub al,30h
    add qty,al
    JMP nextQA

compare2 PROC

    CMP AL,30h
    JL re_askB
    cmp al,39h
    JG re_askB

    ret
compare2 endp

nextQA:

    JMP sAskb
re_askB:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,W_MSG
    INT 21h

sAskb:
    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,askB
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,0AH
    LEA DX,num_list
    INT 21h

    mov Uprice,0

    mov al,number[0]
    call compare2
    sub ax,30h
    mul hundr
    add Uprice,ax

    mov al,number[1]
    call compare2
    sub ax,30h
    mul tens
    add Uprice,ax

    mov al,number[2]
    call compare2
    sub ax,30h
    mov ah,0
    add Uprice,ax
    JMP DO_CAL

DO_CAL:
    mov al,qty
    mov dx,Uprice
    mov ah,0
    mul dx
    mov dx,0
    mov dx,Total2
    mov Total1,ax
    add Total1,dx

    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,reply
    INT 21h

     mov ah, 4Ch
     int 21H
main endp


END MAIN
```

Comment: Use a debugger and pay attention to the values in the registers.